# Crystal reports Layout

Tags: layout, crystal-reports, report

I am using the crystal report integrated in visual studio 2008 to create my reports.
My report design is that its has 3 sections
Section header where
Section detail
Section Footer
However I am having a problem with displaying vertical lines on the detail section when there are no records. The section footer is always displayed at the bottom of the page meaning that i can check the property extend vertical lines to bottom of page when printing.
How do i resolve this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You may need to make sure that the vertical line itself extends to the section footer. If the line is only in the detail section and is not extended to the section above or below it then the line will not show if that section is not shown.